# JavaFX: setText() applied to a label freezes UI in a multithreaded client-server application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I'm currently working on my first client-server project using JavaFX and a socket based connection. The program starts with a login view with two `TextFields`, a `Label` and a a `Button` that sends the access request along with email and password to a server and, in case of 'registered' user, the server allows the user to login. The UI then shows a message in a Label and opens a new view.

Since I read that the thread used by JavaFX shouldn't be used for other computation besides dealing with the UI, as soon as the Button is pressed, a new Thread (private class `LoginThread` in the code below) responsible for the connection with the server is started.

When the LoginThread is over, I want the Label to show a text based on the result of the request. When I insert wrong email or password, it correctly shows the message in the Label saying that the email or password is not valid. But if then, on a second attempt, I put the correct email/password, no message in the Label is shown and the program freezes.

If I remove the `setText()` lines, everything seems working.

This is the Controller code related to the Login view:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private TextField emailField;

    @FXML
    private TextField pswField;

    @FXML
    private Button signButton;

    @FXML
    private Label msgLabel;


    private Socket sock;
    private ObjectOutputStream outStreamObj;
    private ObjectInputStream inStreamObject;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private User allowedUser;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    private class LoginThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
                in = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);

                System.out.println("***CLIENT***");
                System.out.println("Server says: " + in.nextLine());

                out.println(0);
                System.out.println("Server says: " + in.nextLine());

                User unknownUser = new User();
                unknownUser.setEmail(emailField.getText());
                unknownUser.setPassword(pswField.getText());
                unknownUser.setFirstName(null);
                unknownUser.setSecondName(null);

                outStreamObj = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                outStreamObj.writeObject(unknownUser);
                outStreamObj.flush();

                if (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("Server says: " + in.nextLine());
                }

                inStreamObject = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                allowedUser = (User) inStreamObject.readObject();

                if (allowedUser.getEmail().equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("empty email");
                    allowedUser = null;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (sock != null) 
                        sock.close();                    
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initModel() {

        signButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

                LoginThread lt = new LoginThread();
                lt.start();

                try {
                    lt.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                if (allowedUser == null) {
                    msgLabel.setText("Invalid email/password. Try again.");
                    msgLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

                } else {
                    msgLabel.setText("Correct email and password.");
                    msgLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
                    msgLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    BottledMessaging.setCurrentUser(allowedUser);


                    FXMLLoader homeLoader = null;
                    AnchorPane pane = null;
                    try {
                        homeLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLHome.fxml"));
                        pane = homeLoader.load();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    FXMLHomeController homeController = homeLoader.getController();
                    homeController.initModel();
                    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
                    ((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
                }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

The method initController is called in the main method of the Client class.

My Server class below:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    private List<User> userList;
    static Socket socket;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(Socket client, ServerSocket serverSocket) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        userList = getUsers();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            dispatcher();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void dispatcher() throws ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, Exception {

        PrintWriter out = null;
        Scanner in = null;

        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

            out.println("Welcome. I'm your server.");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            if (in.hasNextInt()) {

                int request = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Client requested service: " + request);

                switch (request) {
                    case 0:
                        out.println("Login requested...");
                        login();
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void login() throws ClassNotFoundException, Exception {

        ObjectInputStream inStreamObj = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outStreamObj = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Entered login method. ");
            inStreamObj = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            User guest = (User) inStreamObj.readObject();
            boolean allowed = isAllowedUser(guest);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            if (allowed) {
                System.out.println("Allowed user.");
                User user = getSpecificUser(guest.getEmail());
                String name = user.getFirstName();
                String surname = user.getSecondName();

                out.println("Allowed user. Welcome back, " + name + " " + surname + "!");
                out.flush();
                outStreamObj = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                outStreamObj.writeObject(user);
                outStreamObj.flush();
            } else {
                out.println("You can't access.");
                System.out.println("User not allowed.");
                outStreamObj = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                guest.setEmail("");
                outStreamObj.writeObject(guest);
                outStreamObj.flush();
            }

        } catch (SocketException se) {
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        while (true){
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection accepted.");
            Server server = new Server(socket, serverSocket);
            server.start();
        }

    }
}
```

I read about the possibility to use `Platform.runLater(...)` but as far as I understood this is useful when I want to update my GUI from another Thread, but this is not the case since actually the `setText()` instruction is on the JavaFX thread and it doesn't upload the Label even if I put it as first line in the Button handler method.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated :) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest you use  a `Service` or `Task`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: @Sedrick Instead of the `LoginThread` or just for the `setText()`?

Comment: Instead of `LoginThread`. Refactor that code using `Service` or `Task`. That way you can use `onSucceeded` to update your GUI.

Comment: Since `msgLabel` is annotated with @FXML, it is null until you call FXMLLoader.load.  Also `lt.start()` followed by `lt.join()` is *exactly the same* as not using a thread at all;  you might as well just call `lt.run();` instead.

Comment: `FXMLLoader.load()` is called in the main method of the Client class (not showing in the code above) so I'm pretty sure `msgLabel` is not null also because I don't get any NullPointerException. I put `lt.join()` because I wanted to avoid putting the code in charge of the connection in the JavaFx Thread and at the same time the following line `if (allowedUser == null)` needs to be evaluated once the connection is established and the client receives the information from the server. Am I wrong in what I'm saying? I'm still learning these concurrency mechanisms. @VGR

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Sedrick, I'm gonna try it soon and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: `lt.join()` effectively does run that connection code in the JavaFX application thread, since it waits for the thread to complete.  Following Sedrick’s suggestion would resolve the issue.

Comment: The claim that `lt.join` runs the logic on the application thread is wrong, but the effect is similar: There are 2 threads running until `lt` completes. `lt.join()` waits for the `lt` thread to complete. Performance-wise this is even worse than running the logic on the initial thread, since creating an additional thread and running both results in some overhead...

Comment: I defined `Task connection = new Task() {...}` containing the connection code that previously was in the `LoginThread`, then I called `new Thread(connection).start()` in the `handle(ActionEvent e)` method of the EventHandler of `signButton`. Then, I put all the following code, including the `msgLabel.setText("..")`, in the `handle` method of `connection.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {...});`. I still have the same problem. Where am I wrong?